# Updating nested arrays in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a problem in updating nested objects in Mongoose.

Here is my Schema:

```
var DateModel = mongoose.model(
    'date', new mongoose.Schema({
        date_id: { type: Number, unique: true, required: true },
        students: []
    })
);
```

and my raw `DateModel` looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 5544b62fc852b58c259fba26,
    date_id: 20150502,
    __v: 0,
    students: 
       [ 
           { desc_int: 0, status: 'normal', student_name: 'steve', student_id: 7 },
           { desc_int: 0, status: 'normal', student_name: 'bill', student_id: 31 },
           { desc_int: 0, status: 'normal', student_name: 'eric', student_id: 32 } 
       ] 
}
```

and I'd like to update the `student` with the id `7` with this query:

```
DateModel.update(
    {
        'date_id': id,
        'students.student_id': student_id
    },
    { 
        $set: {
            'students.$.status': status,
            'students.$.desc_int': desc_int
        }
    },
    function (error, rowsAffected) { 
    });
```

But it seems that it doesn't work.

How could I get it working?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It worked fine when I tried it. Make sure both the `id` and `student_id` variables are numbers, not strings. Why haven't you defined a schema for the `students` array? That would take care of any casting needs for you.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. It was because id and student_id variables were strings. I deeply appreciate your help.